# Sql Server 2008 Windows 8.1 installation issue ... SqlEngineConfigAction_install_confignonrc_Cpu64

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-8

I try to install ms sql server 2008 standard on Windows 8.1

.Net framework 3.5 is enabled

setup is running by admin.

following errors will appear:

Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation:

```
SqlEngineConfigAction_install_confignonrc_Cpu64
```

and for the next files (when I'm trying with developer edition):

```
SSISCONFIGACTION_INSTALL_POSTMSI_CPU64

SSISConfigAction_intall_postmsi_Cpu64

SSISConfigAction_intall_ConfigNonRC_Cpu32
```

Could you help me?

You can find applicable part of the file below:

> 2014-10-27 00:25:22 Slp: Parameter 8 : 0x2C419A32
>
> 2014-10-27 00:25:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server to file C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20141026_222703\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Microsoft
> SQL Server.reg_ 2014-10-27 00:25:27 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm
> registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall to
> file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20141026_222703\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_
> 2014-10-27 00:25:28 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\100\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20141026_222703\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_MSSQLServer.reg_
> 2014-10-27 00:25:28 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key
> SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server to file C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20141026_222703\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_Microsoft
> SQL Server.reg_ 2014-10-27 00:25:28 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm
> registry key
> SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall to
> file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20141026_222703\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_
> 2014-10-27 00:25:28 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key
> SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer to file C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20141026_222703\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_MSSQLServer.reg_
> 2014-10-27 00:25:53 Slp: Attempted to perform an unauthorized
> operation. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Watson bucket for exception based
> failure has been created 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Configuration action
> failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigNonRC and
> scenario ConfigNonRC. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Attempted to perform an
> unauthorized operation. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: The configuration
> failure category of current exception is ConfigurationFailure
> 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature
> SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigNonRC and scenario
> ConfigNonRC. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException: Attempted to
> perform an unauthorized operation. --->
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an
> unauthorized operation. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String
> subkey, RegistryAccess requestedAccess) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String
> subkey, RegistryAccess requestedAccess) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String
> subkey, RegistryAccess requestedAccess) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.EtwSetup.UpdateWmiSecurity(Guid
> guidInstance) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.EtwSetup.Install(String
> strInstanceName, Guid guidInstance, String strPath) 2014-10-27
> 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.SetupETW(EffectiveProperties
> properties) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.Install_ConfigNonRC_Prepare(EffectiveProperties
> properties) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.Install(ConfigActionTiming
> timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcb)
> 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.ExecuteAction(String
> actionId) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.Execute(String
> actionId, TextWriter errorStream) 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Exception:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException. 2014-10-27
> 00:25:56 Slp: Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.
> 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Message: Attempted to perform an unauthorized
> operation.. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Inner exception: 2014-10-27
> 00:25:56 Slp:     Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException.
> 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:  Source:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp:
> Message: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.. 2014-10-27
> 00:25:56 Slp: Error: Action
> "SqlEngineConfigAction_install_confignonrc_Cpu64" failed during
> execution. 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Completed Action:
> SqlEngineConfigAction_install_confignonrc_Cpu64, returned False
> 2014-10-27 00:25:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag
> UpgradeIncomplete for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance
> MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER, machine name NN
>
> (...)
>
> 2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp:
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp:  2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp: Error result:
> -2068119551 2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp: Result facility code: 1211 2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp: Result error code: 1 2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp:
> Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
> machine  2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry
> subkey  2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry
> subkey Software\Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting\DW\Installed
> 2014-10-27 00:26:39 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value DW0201
> 2014-10-27 00:26:54 Slp: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data
> repository

Comment: See this discussion at the MS Social Forums for possible solutions: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/61d56f64-2575-4a58-9503-84579476afaf/sql-server-2008-setup-error-attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2) isn't compatible with Windows 8.1. Please read the below Microsoft KB article for more details. Please try for SQL server 2012 or higher version.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562/en-us